# display each day's date python from today

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I was able to display the week that starts every Saturday by:

```
today = now().date()
sat_offset = (today.weekday() - 5) % 7
week_start = today - datetime.timedelta(days=sat_offset)
```

This will display the week from last Saturday but how would I show the dates of each day forward as well? So if the week: Oct. 27, 2018 is display it should say:

Saturday : Oct. 27, 2018
Sunday: Oct. 28, 2018
Monday: Oct. 29, 2018
Tuesday: Oct. 30, 2018
Wednesday: Oct. 31, 2018
Thursday: Nov. 01, 2018
Friday: Nov. 02, 2018

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the days of the week using range and time delta like so:

```
for i in range(7): 
    week_start += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print(week_start.strftime("%A %d. %B %Y"))
```

This will produce a dates like:

- Monday : Oct. 28, 2018
- Tuesday : Oct. 29, 2018
- Wednesday : Oct. 30, 2018
- Thursday : Oct. 31, 2018
- Friday : Nov. 01, 2018
- Saturday : Nov. 02, 2018
- Sunday : Nov. 03, 2018

You can format the string how ever you want. Here is some [info](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#date-objects) on dates in python.